# Error: Syntax: Missing comma or ) in argument list

Tags: julia

I am trying to run the below code and getting the below error -

```
Error: Syntax: Missing comma or ) in argument list
```

Below is the complete code, I watned to create.

```
function tournamentWinner(competetions, results)
    teams = Dict()
    for i in range(1, length(results))
        if (results[i] == 1) && (competetions[i][0] not in teams)
            teams[competetions[i][0]] = 1
        elseif (results[i] == 1) && (competetions[i][0] in teams)
            teams[competetions[i][0]] += 1
        elseif (results[i] == 0) && (competetions[i][1] not in teams)
            teams[competetions[i][1]] = 1
        elseif (results[i] == 0) && (competetions[i][1] in teams)
            teams[competetions[i][1]] += 1
        end
    end
    return findmax(teams)[2]
end
competetions = [["HTML", "Java"],["Java", "Python"], ["Python", "HTML"],["C#", "Python"],["Java", "C#"],["C#", "HTML"]]
    
results = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
tournamentWinner(competetions, results)
```

Comment: can you post the complete code? for example what is `tournamentWinner`? also, `competetions[1][0]` this is gonna give you out of bounds error, Julia is 1-based index

Comment: `(competetions[1][0] not in teams)` is invalid syntax. You want `!(competetions[1][0] in teams)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have updated the code, I was getting the error so was trying to test the part of the code earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me, replaced 'in', 'not in' with 'haskey', '!haskey' for dictionary

```
function tournamentWinner(competetions, results)
    teams = Dict()
    for i in range(1, length(results))
        if (results[i] == 1) && !haskey(teams, competetions[i][1])
            teams[competetions[i][1]] = 1
        elseif (results[i] == 1) && haskey(teams, competetions[i][1])
            teams[competetions[i][1]] += 1
        elseif (results[i] == 0) && !haskey(teams, competetions[i][2])
            teams[competetions[i][2]] = 1
        elseif (results[i] == 0) && haskey(teams, competetions[i][2])
            teams[competetions[i][2]] += 1
        end
    end
    return findmax(teams)[2]
end

competetions = [["HTML", "Java"],["Java", "Python"], ["Python", "HTML"],["C#", "Python"],["Java", "C#"],["C#", "HTML"]]
    
results = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
tournamentWinner(competetions, results)
```